# Xamarin forms : Content View doesn't display in content page

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Am trying to Load a Content View in a Content page. When I run the code it doesn't hit my Content View. I am assigning two Bindable parameters from my content page.

**Content Page:**

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:templates="clr-namespace:G2.Scanner.Views.Templates"           
         xmlns:viewModelBase="clr-namespace:G2.Scanner.ViewModels.Base;assembly=G2.Scanner"              
         xmlns:telerikPrimitives="clr-namespace:Telerik.XamarinForms.Primitives;assembly=Telerik.XamarinForms.Primitives"
         xmlns:local ="clr-namespace:G2.Scanner.Views.Transaction"
         x:Class="G2.Scanner.Views.Transaction.TransactionView"
         viewModelBase:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="true">

        <local:GenerateScreen x:Name="generateScreen" ControllerName="{Binding ControllerName}" IsBusy="{Binding IsBusy}"/>

</ContentPage>
```

**Content View:**

```
public partial class GenerateScreen : ContentView
{
    #region BindableProperties
    public static readonly BindableProperty ControllerNameProperty = BindableProperty.Create("ControllerName", typeof(string), typeof(GenerateScreen));
    public static readonly BindableProperty IsBusyProperty = BindableProperty.Create("IsBusy", typeof(bool), typeof(GenerateScreen));
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    public string ControllerName
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(ControllerNameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ControllerNameProperty, value); }
    }

    public bool IsBusy
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsBusyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsBusyProperty, value); }
    }
    #endregion

    public GenerateScreen()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DesignScreenAsync();
    }

    public async void DesignScreenAsync()
    {
        IsBusy = true;

        // Some Design code..

        #region render
        scroll = new ScrollView
        {
            Content = layout
        };
        TransactionElements.Children.Add(scroll);
        #endregion
        IsBusy = false;
    }
```

Content View accepts two bindable property and is used at the time of load.

**Content View Xaml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="G2.Scanner.Views.Transaction.GenerateScreen">
  <ContentView.Content>
        <StackLayout x:Name="TransactionElements"/>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

I want this view to be rendered at the time content page is loaded.
I figured out that this works if I don't use bindable properties in content view. But as per My requirement **ControllerName** and **IsBusy** in ContentView Class Should be Bindable Property.
Any Help why it's not hitting this View.

Comment: Did you debug your view? are the bindings even set when `DesignScreenAsync` is called?

Comment: @Johannes it doesn't hit the content view class 1st of all. yes, am trying everything by debugging only.

Comment: the breakpoint was put into the constructor and/or the `DesignScreenAsync` method? No one of them was hitten?

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza had put breakpoint in both place but non hits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Thank you** all for taking your time. I actually found a solution for myself.

What actually went wrong was in two places.

1. The bindable properties will be only set after the initialization of the class. So if we call the `DesignScreenAsync` method in the constructor which takes the value of `ControllerName` will obviously have null. the solution is to call the method in `ControllerName`'s `PropertyChanged` method.

Here is the code:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty ControllerNameProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ControllerName), typeof(string), typeof(GenerateScreen),default(string), propertyChanged: OnControllerPropertyChange);

private static void OnControllerPropertyChange(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
{
    ((GenerateScreen)bindable).DesignScreenAsync();
}
```

Notice that I have used `BindableObject` to call the method. This is to call the method from the same instence.

2. The reason why **contentView** was not hitting, is that I didn't set a default value for the bool `IsBusyProperty`, so it is important to set the default value for a bindable property.

Here is the code:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty IsBusyProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(IsBusy), typeof(bool), typeof(GenerateScreen), default(bool), defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay);
```

Answer (score 0):

Defining an async void method is most of the time a bad practice.
To avoid this and probably solve your problem, you have 2 solutions depending on your need.

1) If DesignScreen only builds your UI without intensive call, you must execute it synchronously:

```
  public GenerateScreen()
   {
    InitializeComponent();
    DesignScreenAsync();
   }

   public void DesignScreen()
   {
    IsBusy = true;

    // Some Design code..

    #region render
    scroll = new ScrollView
    {
        Content = layout
    };
    TransactionElements.Children.Add(scroll);
        #endregion
        IsBusy = false;
       }
```

2) If you have intensive calls that need to be awaited. Perform intensive calls and and update UI using Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread:

```
 public async void DesignScreenAsync()
 {
     IsBusy = true;

    await ApiIntensiveCall();
    // Some Design code..

    #region render
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
    {
      scroll = new ScrollView
      {
        Content = layout
      };
      TransactionElements.Children.Add(scroll);
      #endregion
    });

    IsBusy = false;

}
```